# Git: keep color of git stash list --pretty=<..> through a pipe

Tags: text-processing, command-line, git, colors

I have this command:

```
git stash list --pretty="%C(yellow)%h %>(14)%Cgreen%cr %C(blue)%gs"
```

gives output colored, but if I pipe it `git stash list <..> | less -R`, color disappear in output.

How to persist color of `git stash list` via pipe?

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature, because git doesn't know what you are piping to.

You can configure the command to always output colors like this:

```
git -c color.ui=always your command | less -R
```

man git:

> ```
>   -c <name>=<value>
>       Pass a configuration parameter to the command. The value given will
>       override values from configuration files. The
>       <name> is expected in the same format as listed by git config
>       (subkeys separated by dots).
> ```

Another option is to configure `core.pager`:

```
git config core.pager "less -R"
```

So you don't need to pipe to `less` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The right command should be:

```
git stash list --color=always --pretty="%C(yellow)%h %>(14)%Cgreen%cr %C(blue)%gs"
```

Add option `--color=always`